# Underscore's _.isEqual can't distinguish 2 images

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

My app use `Backbone.js`, and have some issue to catch the change event on image, because it use `Underscore.js`'s `_.isEqual` to decide whether an attribute is changed or not, however, it doesn't work on `img`:

```js
// Backbone inits.
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    image : null
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this, 'change', this.handleChange);
  },
  handleChange: function(model) {
    var changes = this.changedAttributes();
    if (changes) {
      for (var k in changes) {
        console.log(k + 'in the model changed.', this.get(k));
      }
    }
  }
});

var testModel  = new Model();
console.log(testModel.get('image'));

// Test change work
testModel.set('testval', 1);
testModel.set('testval', 2);
             
var canvas = document.querySelector('#testCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

var canvas2 = document.querySelector('#testCanvas2');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

ctx2.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 50);


var image1 = new Image();
var image2 = new Image();
image1.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('#test').appendChild(image1);
  
    // backbone 
    testModel.set('image', image1);
    
    image2.onload = function() {
        document.querySelector('#test').appendChild(image2);
      
        testModel.set('image', image2); // This not fire
      
        console.log("Use isEqual : ",_.isEqual(image1, image2));
        console.log("Use == : ", image1 == image2);
        console.log("Use === : ", image1 === image2);
    };
    image2.src = canvas2.toDataURL();
};
image1.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <canvas id="testCanvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
    <canvas id="testCanvas2" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, I created 2 canvas and draw different rectangle, then use `.toDataURL()` to put canvas to image, and use `_.isEqual` to check if the images are same or not.

Expect : The `_.isEqual` to return false, as use `==` or `===`.

Get: The `_.isEqual` return true while others return false.

As I use minfied backbone and underscore, is there any way that let me get `false` from `_.isEqual` while not altering `Backbone` and `Underscore`?

Comment: can you show an example of how backbone does not see the change? Could you just also change another property on the img?

Comment: @k-nut Added the backbone example.

Comment: Could you instead of setting `image` in you model just store the img src like this? `testModel.set('image', image2.src); `

Comment: I think I'll take it as last resort, as the way will get into some legacy code, which may affect much of the app as that image is widely used to compute other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `_.isEqual` to customize how instances of `Image` are handled :

```
(function() {
    var _equal = _.isEqual;
      _.isEqual = function(a, b) {
        if ((a instanceof Image) && (b instanceof Image))
            return a.src === b.src;
        else
            return _equal(a, b);
      };
}());
```

```js
(function() {
    var _equal = _.isEqual;
      _.isEqual = function(a, b) {
        if ((a instanceof Image) && (b instanceof Image))
            return a.src === b.src;
        else
            return _equal(a, b);
      };
}());


// Backbone inits.
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    image : null
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this, 'change', this.handleChange);
  },
  handleChange: function(model) {
    var changes = this.changedAttributes();
    if (changes) {
      for (var k in changes) {
        console.log(k + 'in the model changed.', this.get(k));
      }
    }
  }
});

var testModel  = new Model();
console.log(testModel.get('image'));

// Test change work
testModel.set('testval', 1);
testModel.set('testval', 2);
             
var canvas = document.querySelector('#testCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);

var canvas2 = document.querySelector('#testCanvas2');
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

ctx2.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 50);


var image1 = new Image();
var image2 = new Image();
image1.onload = function() {
    document.querySelector('#test').appendChild(image1);
  
    // backbone 
    testModel.set('image', image1);
    
    image2.onload = function() {
        document.querySelector('#test').appendChild(image2);
      
        testModel.set('image', image2); // This not fire
      
        console.log("Use isEqual : ",_.isEqual(image1, image2));
        console.log("Use == : ", image1 == image2);
        console.log("Use === : ", image1 === image2);
    };
    image2.src = canvas2.toDataURL();
};
image1.src = canvas.toDataURL();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
    <canvas id="testCanvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
    <canvas id="testCanvas2" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

That, of course, may break horribly other parts of your code that could rely on the original behavior. And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/ecr16wzc/ to play with.

Comment: I got to test it later tomorrow to see if it solves the problem but crash the other part lol, anyway, upvoted with appreciation.